# Compute the limit:

Tags: limits, trigonometry

$$ \lim_{x \geq 0}{\frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{x\sin(2x)}}$$
I tried:
$$\lim_{x \geq 0}{{\frac{1-\cos^2(x)*\cos(x)}{2*x*\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}}}$$
$$\lim_{x \geq 0}{\frac{\cos^2x+\sin^2x-\cos^2(x)\cos(x)}{2*x*\sin^2x*\cos^2(x)}}$$
$$\lim_{x \geq 0}{\frac{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)-(1-\sin^2(x))\cos(x)}{2*x*\sin^2(x)*\cos^2(x)}}$$
$$\lim_{x \geq 0}{\frac{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)-\cos(x)+\sin^2(x)\cos(x)}{2*x*\sin^2(x)*\cos^2(x)}}$$
Somewhere I over-complicated and I don't know how to continue or the other route  that I should take...

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{1-\cos^3x}{x\sin(2x)}$$
Apply L'Hopital's Rule$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{1-\cos^3x}{x\sin(2x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{3\cos^2x\sin x}{\sin(2x)+2x\cos(2x)}$$
Again apply L'Hopital's Rule
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\dfrac{3(-\sin(2x)\sin x+\cos^3x)}{4\cos(2x)-4x\sin(2x)}=\dfrac34$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$${\frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{x\sin(2x)}}={\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}}\cdot(1+\cos x+\cos^2(x))\cdot\frac12{\frac{2x}{\sin(2x)}}$$

then refer to standard limits

- $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\to \frac12$
- $\frac{2x}{\sin(2x)}\to 1$

and simply

- $1+\cos x+\cos^2(x)\to 3$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write
$$\frac{(1-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x))(\cos^2(x)+\cos(x)+1)}{2x\sin(x)\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos^3x}{x \sin (2x)}&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\left( 1-\frac{x^2}2\right)^3}{2x^2}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-(1-\frac{3x^2}2)}{2x^2} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac32x^2}{2x^2}\\
&= \frac34\end{align}

Comment: What is the step in between the first computation, where you get rid of trigonometric identities

Comment: taylor series, just drop the higher order terms.

Comment: I always suggest to include remainder terms (in little-o or big-O form) when using Taylor's expansion, especialy when we introduce to the method not expert student.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write the expression under limit as $$\frac{1-\cos ^3x}{1-\cos x} \cdot\frac{1-\cos x} {x^2}\cdot\frac{2x}{\sin 2x}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$ The first fraction tends to $3$, the second one tends to $1/2$, and the third one tends to $1$ and therefore the desired limit is $3/4$.